# Make a view to be the primary one in navigation controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am using a tabbar, each tab having a navigation controller, and this in turn having a stack of views. Each view is having its own view controller but this is not important now.

Lets have a tab 1 with a navigation controller 1 with views A, B, C. 
The nature of the application dictates however that the view B is the primary one.

So what I want is that by default (after first or after relaunch of the app), when I tap the tab 1, I will see the B view together with the back button to A view.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why I find myself that I cannot understand your question? Damn it!!!

Comment: To understand the question properly, one has to firmly understand the difference between views and controllers, understand that viewcontrollers have a built-in main view, understand the typical tabbed app hierarchy that is UITabbarController -> UINavigationController -> stack of any ViewControllers. And understand the typical UI workflow of such an app.
I imply all these things in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a delegate for your tab bar controller and implement `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` to detect when someone taps a tab.  If you detect that A is about to be selected and you want B to be displayed instead, you can tell A's controller to use its navigation controller to push B's controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing and pushing view B (without animation) onto the navigation stack in viewDidLoad of view A.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `setViewControllers:animated:` of UINavigationController.
Depending on your exact needs you could set this in your app delegate `applicationWillEnterForeground:` or `applicationDidBecomeActive:` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I recall there being an Apple sample app that does exactly this. The general idea is to save the last visible view controller (or just hard code the one you want) and then push it to the visible state using something like so:

`[myNavigationController pushViewController:viewControllerToBeVisible animate:NO];`

You'd want to show the apps `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`, and handle the different cases based on which viewController was selected.